# Incorrect sum of decimal values in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, decimal

I'm pulling data from a T-SQL procedure, one of my columns is cast as numeric(18,2)

When i run this procedure and copy the data to excel, the sum on this column is 0.01 less than the sum i get when i run this on vb.net.

In vb.net, i am aggregating the values for the column into a dictionary(of string, decimal)

I don't know why this happening.

```
   If Not dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal(f.field)) Then
        Dim dval = If(dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal(f.field)), 0D, dr.GetDecimal(dr.GetOrdinal(f.field)))
        di.Add(New FieldValue With {.Type = f, .Value = If(rpt.allow_negatives, dval, Math.Abs(dval))}, rpt.overide_format)
        If rpt.has_total AndAlso f.totaled Then totals(f.field) += dval
    Else
        di.Add(New FieldValue With {.Type = f, .Value = 0D})
    End If
```

Comment: I am using Math.Abs ... this returns a double. Could that be an issue, converting between decimal and double?

Comment: Math.Abs even has a decimal overload...so it's not likely to be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.Abs has a `decimal` overload, so it is probably not that.  More likely it is Excel that is getting the calculation wrong.  Excel typically throws away anything more than 15 digits of precision.

See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

To prove this to yourself, type

```
 1234567890123456.78
```

into an Excel cell.  You'll see that the number ends up being :

```
 1234567890123450
```

Comment: @j My total is way smaller than that 96101515696.33 in VB but 96101515696.32 in excel

Comment: @CharlesO -I'd still suspect Excel.  You're at 13 digits out of 15 for total precision and Excel is converting to double for all of your values.  Not all of your values will be exactly representable as doubles so they will all collect errors around the 15-17th digit of precision.  If you're adding a lot of numbers this can really add up.  That's why the `decimal` format exists.  You can recode your VB to use `double` instead of `decimal` and see if you don't get the same result as Excel.

Comment: @j this is strange...i ensure numeric(18,2) right from t-sql to make sure i am dealing with only 2 decimal places.

Comment: @CharlesO - yes, only two decimal places, but you also have up to 13 digits of precision.  When you convert to double (ie: in Excel) you always have leftovers.  For example - 12345.68 as a double is not exactly representable.  The closest double is 1.23456800000000002910383045673E4 - so you start accumulating error in the 18th digit of precision.  After you add up these errors over a large number of values you start to see the errors creep into higher digits of precision.  It's not about decimal places, it's about digits of precision.

Comment: @CharlesO - you may want to try this : http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/set-rounding-precision-HA010218870.aspx